# IdentityServer4 and .NET Core Identity client doesn't logout on security stamp change

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm trying to implement only one sign in per user functionality. Basically when the user signs in from a different browser or from a different location, the old sessions for the user(including the clients) are invalidated. In my code, when the security stamp is automatically updated via  `_userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(loggedinUser);` call, the server logs the user out but the clients connected to it doesn't logout. When I logout manually from the server, the clients logout without a problem. (I have set the FrontChannelLogoutUri from the IdentityServer config ). Is there a solution to this(like which methods should I override to implement a custom logout) or an alternative?

Comment: That's two completely separate issues. When you logout the user in core identity, the tokes are still valid (until they expire) unless you revoke the tokens too. When you use JWT token, thats a bit more difficult since its self-contained. If you use an opaque token ("reference token" in IdSrv4 terminology), the token will be validated against the IdSrv4. But by default its not checked on every request, but the response is cached locally and only revalidated after the cache expires, see http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/revocation.html

Comment: As well as http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html but though that may not work in your case, since you need to know the access (reference) token in order to revoke a token (though you may do that on the clients to and identify the tokens with a unique value but it requires a lot more infrastructure, such as a messaging queue and/or distributed memory caches).